# PYQT and embedding matplotlib: Graph not showing

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

Hello im trying to add a custom graph to the pyqt interface I have.  Its not showing any data, but the placeholder matplotlib graph is showing.  Any help?!  Also If i plot just the graph data without putting it into PYQT, it shows up.  Thanks!

```
class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
"""Ultimately, this is a QWidget (as well as a FigureCanvasAgg, etc.)."""
def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
    fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
    #self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
    # We want the axes cleared every time plot() is called
    self.axes.hold(False)

    self.compute_initial_figure()
    FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
    self.setParent(parent)

    FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                               QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                               QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
    FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

def compute_initial_figure(self):
    pass


class MyStaticMplCanvas(MyMplCanvas):

def mystatic(self, parent=None):
    super(MyStaticMplCanvas, self).__init__(parent)

    rate,data = read('test.wav') # reading
    subplot(411)
    self.plot(range(len(data)),data)
    subplot(412)
    self.specgram(data, NFFT=128, noverlap=0) # small window
    subplot(413)
    self.specgram(data, NFFT=512, noverlap=0) 
    subplot(414)
    self.specgram(data, NFFT=1024, noverlap=0) # big window

    self.show()


class ApplicationWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        l = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.main_widget)
        sc = MyStaticMplCanvas(self.main_widget, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)

        l.addWidget(sc)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code sample you provided, there is no call to the *mystatic* method that you use to plot your data. Therefore, nothing is plotted on your figure.

Moreover, It seems you are using the *pyplot* interface for plotting your data by calling directly `subplot` and `plot` for example in *mystatic*. When embedding a mpl figure in an application, it is recommended from the [mpl documentation](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html) to stick to the object oriented API.

I've produced a minimal working example from the code you've provided that follows the guidelines provided in the aforementioned documentation. Hope it helps.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl    
mpl.use('Qt4Agg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):        
        fig = mpl.figure.Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)   
        fig.set_tight_layout('tight')
        super(MyMplCanvas, self).__init__(fig)

class MyStaticMplCanvas(MyMplCanvas):

    def mystatic(self, parent=None):

        x, y = np.random.rand(50), np.random.rand(50)
        ax1 = self.figure.add_subplot(411)
        ax1.plot(x,y, '.')
        ax2 = self.figure.add_subplot(412)
        ax2.plot(x,y, '.')
        ax3 = self.figure.add_subplot(413)
        ax3.plot(x,y, '.')
        ax4 = self.figure.add_subplot(414)
        ax4.plot(x,y, '.')

if __name__ == '__main__' :

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MyStaticMplCanvas(width=5, height=6, dpi=100)
    w.mystatic()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

which results in:

[image]